# Import a csv file to a list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, csv

I have [this](https://pastebin.com/3qKVrxed) csv file created using `writerow` function from the csv module. The file has 63 lines. I want to create a list of lists in python from this file.

I tried the following code:

```
import csv

dataset = []

def importCsv(file):
    x = 0
    print(dataset)
    with open(file, newline='') as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in data:
            #print(type(row))
            dataset.append(row)
            x += 1
        print(x)

importCsv(csvPath)
```

But when I try `print(len(dataset))`, it outputs 126 instead of 63. I am really confused. Why is the number of items in dataset so high?

Comment: an example of the content of the CSV file should be usefull

Comment: Try printing `row` inside the `for` loop to see what is being added to `dataset`

Comment: 126 = 63*2. Make sure that your file doesn't have spurious CR (carriage return) chars (the infamous windows CSV write bug) which makes a blank line after every line.

Comment: if `open(file, "w",newline='')` (newline it is): if newline is omitted, then the bug occurs on windows: extra blank line after each line

Comment: The problem is the input file.  Check it with a hex editor and make sure the line endings aren't `\r\r\n` instead of `\n` or `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mostly due to spurious CarriageReturn `\r` chars, causing some empty rows to appear. You can skip empty rows by adding an explicit check

```
    for row in data:
        if row:
            dataset.append(row)
            x += 1
```

Comment: `row` isn't a string, but it's a list. the issue is in the input file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. You are right... I have updated the answer